# Adding an integer to every value in a list of integers

Tags: python

Feeling like an utter moron because I KNOW I know how to do this...

I have a list of a bunch of numbers:

```
nums = [100,200,300,400,500]
```

I would like to add 1 to all of these numbers, and copy that over to a new list, while preserving the old list. So I'd end up with

```
nums = [100,200,300,400,500]
moreNums = [101,201,301,401,501]
evenMoreNums = [102,202,302,402,502]
```

Is there a simple way to do this or is the easiest way still going to be something like

```
for i in range (nums):
    moreNums.append(i + 1)
```

? (I don't know enough to know off the top of my head if that will work, but I know how to fix it if it doesn't...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[List comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) (or the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for same):

```
nums = [100,200,300,400,500]
nums = [e+1 for e in nums]
# etc
```

Example:

```
>>> nums=range(100,600,100)
>>> nums
[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
>>> nums=[e+1 for e in nums]
>>> nums
[101, 201, 301, 401, 501]
>>> nums=[e+1 for e in nums]
>>> nums
[102, 202, 302, 402, 502]
```

Or, if you want to use exactly your names:

```
>>> nums=range(100,600,100)
>>> moreNums=[e+1 for e in nums]
>>> evenMoreNums=[e+1 for e in moreNums]
>>> print nums,moreNums,evenMoreNums
[100, 200, 300, 400, 500] [101, 201, 301, 401, 501] [102, 202, 302, 402, 502]
```

Comment: Awesome- I actually didn't know either of these ways, so now I have two new things to play with. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
In [65]: nums = [100,200,300,400,500]

In [66]: nums1 = [x + 1 for x in nums]

In [67]: nums1
Out[67]: [101, 201, 301, 401, 501]
```

Comment: Awesome- I actually didn't know either of these ways, so now I have two new things to play with. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you seek another way:

```
nums = [100,200,300,400,500]
map(lambda x: x+1, nums)
```

Have a look at [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) when you want to apply simple functions to all the items of list